# Set instance in script AS2

Tags: flash, instance, actionscript-2

Is it possible to set an instance name for a MC in its script?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In AS2, MovieClips have a [_name](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/AS2LCR/Flash_10.0/help.html?content=00001274.html) property that you can get and set.